# Dynamic base href link with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I just moved from systemjs to webpack as I moved to Angular-CLI.
It used to work but it does not anymore.
Here is what I have :

In my index.html in

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var base = document.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    document.write('<base href="/' + base + '" />');
</script>
```

And I also added a "/" at the root of the few js files added bellow.

Now that I'm on webpack, those files are loaded from somewhere else and I can't add this "/" anymore.
So it is trying to load  them on http://www.exemple.com/it/xxx.js, instead of http://www.exemple.com/xxx.js

I've seen that I have to update something in webpack.config.js file but angular-cli guys have decided to put it in their module and not on the project root as usual.
I know I could edit this file but I don't want to do it again everytime I update angular-cli.

Is there a good way to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

> When building you can modify base tag () in your
>   index.html with --base-href your-url option.

```
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
ng build --bh /myUrl/
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml

Comment: Thanks for your time! Yes I've seen that but I would like to have 1 source for all counties and I feel like it I do `ng build --bh /it/`, I will a source exclusive to this country. Am I wrong ?

Comment: We have the same issue, the way we are currently resolving it is updating the base-href with a python script when we deploy the app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the provider in your @NgModule annotation:

```
@NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,...    ],
        providers: [
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},... ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
}) 
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I did not know this one. Thanks! I'll have a look.